# How to remove "@" symbol from excel formula using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove "@" from the excel formula using a pandas dataframe but it's not working. Can anybody please help me out?

**Excel formula:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(records!$V$2:$V$94,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,@records!$V$2:$V$94),0)),"")
```

**Code I am using to remove "@" symbol:**

```
df_summary['colname'] = df_summary['colname'].str.replace('@', '')
df_summary['colname'] = df_summary['colname'].str.replace('@', '=IFERROR(INDEX(records!$V$2:$V$94,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,@records!$V$2:$V$94),0)),"")')
```

Both the two above ways are not working.

**Expected formula:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(records!$V$2:$V$94,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,records!$V$2:$V$94),0)),"")
```

Comment: The code in your first try should work. The formula is a row in the `colname` column (of string type) of the `df_summary` dataframe, correct?

Comment: Why do you want to remove `@`? Often it is automatically added by newer (and so not new) Excel to stress that you are using old syntax (so literally the values specified), and not as an automatic `#` as interpreted on new Excel. A file opened with old excel will not see it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the excel formula gives the unique value from the record sheet  of column V. However, with "@" symbol it is not giving desired value. If " @"  is removed manually in excel sheet then it is giving the desired result

Comment: @Shaido Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not able to manipulate formulas in excel. Pandas is working directly with the result of the formula. You need to use openpyxl or excelwings